# Rattle in iOS and running the GUI in iOS

Tags: ios, rattle

I am taking a class that needs rattle. I was able to install rattle, but I cannot get the GUI, how to do I get the GUI that my professor shows in class? (he runs Windows and says he doesn't know about iOS installation issues). I am running iOS Monterey, and the latest versions of R and RStudio. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reviewing [ask]. Your first step should always be ***searching***. Quick search for  `rstudio rattle macOS` comes up with this:  https://zhiyzuo.github.io/installation-rattle/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.